# AJAX request don't stop after page closed

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my php Page,
I have a AJAX request in every second.

That mean the AJAX in page refresh once per second.

But when I refresh the page, the page have an error which tell me the status of AJAX is 0...

I believe that the AJAX come back after I refresh the page, and it cannot work normally,

So if I delete the AJAX request before I refresh each time, would I solve it??
and how to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AJAX error of 0 means that there was a network error. This usually happens when a connection is dropped or aborted for whatever reason. In Internet Explorer you may see "funky" error codes in the 12000 area, which can lend some insight into exactly why there was a network error.

In this case, what's happening is that you are forcibly aborting an AJAX request by reloading the page, thus resulting in an error 0.

Personally, I wrote my AJAX function to retry after a few seconds if it gets a 0 error, rather than throwing an ugly error message. For instance, if my internet connection drops due to a power outage, the site will just keep trying every few seconds (each of which fails instantly due to lack of a connection) until it finds the server again, without the user having any kind of inconveninence. In the case of a page reload, the `setTimeout` will never complete so the "retry" doesn't happen, giving a clean end.